# Interfacing atxmega128a with SD Card

Tags: xmega, atxmega

So I was trying to write a code to connect an SD card to my atxmega128 . Code is nearly ready but when I want to compile it in Atmel Studio, I get errors about not declaring some codes. Some of the undeclared codes are "PORTD , PORTD_DIR, ... " . 
Question : Aren't these port codes part of the atmel studio software? Do I need to define some source codes for them ? What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: Did you forget to include `<avr/io.h>`? Are you writing IAR code for the GCC compiler?

Comment: Nope! I didn't forget that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sort of things should be included in avr/io.h, which you should be including at some point.  Check to make sure you have

```
#include <avr/io.h>
```

in the appropriate locations (top of C files and/or included header files).

Comment: I've included io.h and iox128a.h . problem still remains. actually there's nothing about ports and port_dir in these h files.

Comment: try #include "avr/io.h"

Comment: There is no iox128a.h.  Only iox128a1.h, iox128a1u.h, iox128a3.h, iox128a3u.h, and iox128a4u.h.  All of these files define PORTD and PORTD_DIR, among many other things.  However, you should not have to include anything beyond avr/io.h as this file will automatically include the device-specific file.  Are you correctly specifying what the target device is to the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASF then put an include to asf.h in the header file of the part you're working on. It's the easiest way to fix any of these problems.

```
#include <asf.h>
```